# manipulate POST data after sending it to PHP from PYTHON

Tags: php, python, json, sharing

I have an internal server that is generating JSON every few minutes. I need to pass this to and external server so I can manipulate the data and then present it in web interface.
Here is my python that send the data to PHP script:

```
x = json.dumps(data)

print '\nHTTP Response'

headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("myurl.com")

conn.request("POST", "/recieve/recieve.php", x, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
text = response.read()
print "Response status: ",response.status,"\n",text
conn.close()
```

and Here is my PHP to receive the data

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$objJson = json_decode($data);
print_r ($objJson);
```

My python script return with response status 200 which is good and it returns my JSON. But on the PHP side I want to be able to store this information to manipulate and then have a web client grab at it. However it appears that even if I  say

```
print_r ($objJson);
```

when I visit the .php page it does not print out my object. I suppose the data is gone because file::input will read only and then end?

Comment: what does it it print? `Array()` or nothing? What does `strlen($data)` print?

Comment: strlen($data) print 2512

Comment: hmm, and what does `print_r($data)` print?

Comment: it returns a blank page in chrome but reponse to python is HTTP Response
Response status:  200 + the JSON back

Comment: check out code of page (Ctrl+U) - you defenitely recieve rather long string, maybe `echo htmlspecialchars($data)` will show it

Comment: shows nothing oh well might have to see how to wrap a name container in python on the send off

Comment: Hmm  - yeah, unfortunately, I am not familiar with python, but I can certainly tell you that if the POST request is sending data, you wouldn't have to use php://input to get it -- albeit, that is another way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `file_get_contents()`

Just:

```
if($_POST){ echo "WE got the data"; }
```

and `print_r` will help you with where to go from there, if you are unfamiliar with PHP arrays.

Comment: ok so I triedprint_r($_POST);
$objJson = json_decode("$_POST");
print_r($objJson);

Comment: but it only gives me a Array ( ).

Comment: if($_POST){ echo "WE got the data"; } returns notihng I guess nothing is actually being sent $_POST

Answer (score 0):

Try to use named parameter containing your JSON data while sending data to PHP and try to use the [$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) superglobal array in PHP (because you obviously connecting via cgi or similar interface not via cli). 
You can see all the POST data by printing your $_POST array:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did in the end as a quick fix

the python

```
x = json.dumps(data)
headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("myurl.com")

conn.request("POST", "/script.php", x, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
text = response.read()
print "Response status: ",response.status,"\n",text
conn.close()
```

then I realized that the PHP was receiving the post data but I was having a hard time manipulating it. So I just sent the JSON to a receiving PHP file that wrote the data as file and then has another JavaScript request grab that.
the php

```
if($_POST){ echo "WE got the data\n"; } //thanks rm-vanda
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$file = 'new.json';
$handle = fopen($file, 'a');
fwrite($handle, $data);
fclose($handle);
exit;
```

Then from my client just a ajax request for the file and parsed it on the client side.

Eventually I have to rethink this but it works for now. I also have to rewrite over the new.json file each time new data comes in or parse the old data out on the JavaScript success callback. Depends what you want to do.